# Seaborn visualize groups

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

How can I plot this data frame using seaborn to show the KPI per model?

```
allFrame = pd.DataFrame({'modelName':['first','second', 'third'],
                           'kpi_1':[1,2,3],
                           'kpi_2':[2,4,3]})
```

Not like `sns.barplot(x="kpi2", y="kpi1", hue="modelName", data=allFrame)`
[image]
But rather like this per KPI
[image]

Comment: Not too familiar with `seaborn` but I would try melting the dataframe first and then plot: `allFrame2 = pd.melt(frame=allFrame, id_vars=['modelName'], value_vars=["kpi_1","kpi_2"], value_name="Values", var_name="kpis"); sns.barplot(x="kpis", y="Values", hue="modelName", data=allFrame2)`.

Comment: Matplotlib or any other framework would be fine as well - I just suggested seaborn because  I was trying to use it myself.

Comment: Indeed that works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good. I will add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `melt`ing the dataframe first, and then you can plot using `seaborn`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

allFrame = pd.DataFrame({'modelName':['first','second', 'third'],
                           'kpi_1':[1,2,3],
                           'kpi_2':[2,4,3]})
allFrame2 = pd.melt(frame=allFrame, 
                          id_vars=['modelName'], 
                          value_vars=["kpi_1","kpi_2"], 
                          value_name="Values", var_name="kpis")

sns.barplot(x="kpis", y="Values", hue="modelName", data=allFrame2)
```

Thanks!