# Histograms grouping by two criteria [python]

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, seaborn

I have a dataset like this:
[image]

I need to plot this dataset based on two criteria: Churn and Cust_Value.

I can do it using seaborn:

```
sns.barplot(x="Cust_Value", y="value", hue="Churn", data=merged)
plt.show()
```

The result gives me:
[image]

How can I add all variables (value, age, reloads, calls, duration, sms, gprs, inactive) to the same graph as groups of bars?

Comment: Try melting the data as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679431/seaborn-visualize-groups).

Answer (score 1):

for that kind of output i would recommend using plotly,

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=DF['Cust_Value'],
    y=DF['value'],
    name='value'
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=DF['Cust_Value'],
    y=DF['age'],
    name='age'
)
trace3 = go.Bar(
    x=DF['Cust_Value'],
    y=DF['calls'],
    name='calls'
)

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='grouped-bar')
```

sample output:

[image]

reference: https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/

hope it helps!

if it does upvote :)

peace